# Are there published testimonies from Latter-day Saints about their personal experiences with the constant companionship of the Holy Ghost?

Tags: lds, pneumatology, resource-request, doctrine-and-covenants, testimony

I'm very intrigued by the concept of *constant companionship of the Holy Ghost* taught by the LDS church. This is mentioned in [Doctrine and Covenants 121:46](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/121):

> 46 **The Holy Ghost shall be thy constant companion**, and thy scepter an unchanging scepter of brighteousness and truth; and thy cdominion shall be an everlasting dominion, and without compulsory means it shall flow unto thee forever and ever.

According to [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84055/50422), the *constant companionship of the Holy Ghost* is a blessing that only Latter-day Saints can enjoy. No other denomination has access to this privilege:

> [...] **only those who are baptized and confirmed as members of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints can receive the Gift of the Holy Ghost**. Once they have received the Gift, they must live worthy of it in order to maintain the constant companionship of the Holy Ghost.
>
> **Those who are not baptized** can still experience some of the Power of the Holy Ghost, receive certain Revelations, and feel the influence of the Light of Christ, but they **do not have the promise of constant companionship from the Holy Ghost**.
>
> What does that mean in practical terms? **The constant companionship of the Holy Ghost is the state of being "born of the Spirit" which Christ mentions in John 3:5**, saying "Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God". Thus, in order to achieve our full potential and eventually live with God in His kingdom, we must receive the Gift of the Holy Ghost and strive to keep our covenants. Those who do not do this will be unable to receive all that God has prepared for them in the eternities.

The *constant companionship of the Holy Ghost*, thus, appears to be a very special kind of bond or relationship between a LDS believer and the Holy Ghost which Christians from other denominations are deprived of. Hence my interest to learn more about it. However, instead of reading a theoretical definition of the concept, I would rather learn from the testimonies of Latter-day Saints who have personally experienced this special connection with the Holy Ghost firsthand.

**Question**: Has any Latter-day Saint published detailed descriptions of their personal experiences with the *constant companionship of the Holy Ghost*?

Comment: "the constant companionship of the Holy Ghost is a blessing that only Latter-day Saints can enjoy. No other denomination has access to this privilege" I wonder how the LDS Church thinks it knows this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to answer, as how do you properly separate instances of being inspired from having the constant companionship of the Holy Ghost?

It's hard to tell what answer exactly would do this question justice. [Here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/hearhim/?lang=eng), we have a collection of blog posts where the apostles each tell something about how they #HearHim, meaning Hear the voice of Jesus Christ, meaning the Holy Ghost.

There are many, many talks from general conferences which contain personal experiences with the Holy Ghost, but most often not in the context of "constant companionship with the Holy Ghost", simply in the context of whatever the talk is about.

Lastly, "Having the constant companionship of the Holy Ghost" is not simply a state, it's a constant struggle to stay in contact, if you will, and to recognize and understand the Holy Ghost. The gift of the Holy Ghost is basically just the promise that the other side of the connection is always open.

https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-21-the-gift-of-the-holy-ghost?lang=eng

> However, there is no guarantee that the person will receive
> inspiration and guidance from the Holy Ghost just because the elders
> have laid their hands on his or her head. Each person must “receive
> the Holy Ghost.” This means that the Holy Ghost will come to us only
> when we are faithful and desire help from this heavenly messenger.